# Синонимизировать метки [координаты] и [coordinates]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

- [координаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b) (119 вопросов)
- [coordinates](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) (40 вопросов)

*(у обеих нет описания)*

Основная - [координаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b), т. к. она на русском.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 46 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 40 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 39 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'coordinates': [coordinates] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 158
tag remapping of [координаты] and [coordinates] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym coordinates -> координаты was approved!
```